# How to display a number of images depending on property value

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have this class :

```
import {Hero} from "./hero";

export class Deck {
    deckId: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    score: number;
    hero: Hero;
    aspectOrder: number;
    aspectWisdom: number;
    aspectNature: number;
    aspectRage: number;
    aspectDominion: number;
    aspectCorruption: number;
    date : Date;
}
```

and this component :

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {DataService} from "../services/data.service";
import {Deck} from '../entities/deck';
import {Hero} from '../entities/hero';

@Component({
    selector: 'all-decks',
    templateUrl: '/angular/alldecks',
    styleUrls:['../../css/angular/allDecks.css'] 
})
export class AllDecksView implements OnInit {
    private decks: Deck[];
    private deck: Deck;
    private errorMessage: string;

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.GetDecks();
    }

    GetDecks() {
        this.dataService.getAllDecks().subscribe(
            res =>  this.decks = <Deck[]>res,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

with this template :

```
<all-decks>
    <div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="danger">{{errorMessage}}</div>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Deck Name</th>
                <th>Hero</th>
                <th>Aspects</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Updated</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="#deck of decks">
                    <td>{{deck.name}}</td>
                    <td> {{deck.hero.name}}</td>
                    <td>TO DO</td>
                    <td>{{deck.score}}</td>
                    <td>{{deck.date}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</all-decks>
```

What I would like to do is in the aspects column to display a number of identical small images for each aspect corresponding to it's value. For example if the deck has

> aspectOrder = 3

and

> aspectWisdom = 2

there would be 3 "Order" images and 2 "Wisdom" images. 
I can use *ngIf to determine if there should be any images at all for each aspect and get the correct image, but I have no idea how to create the specific number of images :

```
<div *ngIf="deck.aspectOrder>0">[must have exactly 3 images here]</div>
```

and the end result in browser should be something like this :

```
<div>
  <img src="/img/AspectOrder.png"/>
  <img src="/img/AspectOrder.png"/>
  <img src="/img/AspectOrder.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to have just `3 orders and 2 wisdom` in aspects column from json object? or scenario is something like that there may be an empty value too.

Comment: I can use *ngIf..... that is quite conflicting statement. Tell clearly what do you want.

Comment: There can't be an empty value, but it can be 0, that's what I mean I can use *ngIf for : <div *ngIf="deck.aspectOrder>0">[must have 3 order images here]</div>

Comment: Yes, you are right, my bad. Fixed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go this way,

```
<td> 
     <div*ngIf="deck.aspectOrder>0">{{deck.aspectOrder}} Order   
        <div>
              <img src="/img/AspectOrder.png"/>
              <img src="/img/AspectOrder.png"/>
              <img src="/img/AspectOrder.png"/>
        </div>
     </div>  
</td>
```

**UPDATE** :

I hope this answer will help you. it displays img according to orders number.

If you want `<img>` tag dyanmically, I think you have to play at `Typescript` end before you make your bindings to html template.Consider below answer and also check

**[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UAZwj6?p=preview)**.

I tried to stick to your code but don't know how relevant it is,

```
<div *ngFor="#deck of decks">

      <h4>{{deck.name}}- {{deck.orders}} Orders</h4>
      <div *ngFor="#a of deck.finalArray">
          <img src="/img/AspectOrder.png"/>
      </div>

</div>
```

---

```
export class App {
  decks:Deck[];
  constructor(){ 

            this.decks= [
              { "deckId": 1, "orders":"3","name":"deck1" },
              { "deckId": 2, "orders":"2","name":"deck2" },
              { "deckId": 3, "orders":"1","name":"deck3" },
              { "deckId": 4, "orders":"0","name":"deck4" }
            ]

             // This is what I am doing here by putting some logic

             this.decks.forEach(item=> {
                let tempArr=[];
                if(item.orders>0)
                {
                    for (let i=0;i<item.orders;i++)
                    {
                      tempArr.push('');
                    }
                    item.finalArray=tempArr;
                }
            })
            console.log(this.decks);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know but I would prefer to do it with the images.

Comment: I don't get you. you mean to say with `<img>` tag?

Comment: Okay ! But how do you get `src` value? you don't have it in your object properties !

Comment: I input it by hand, the only problem is getting the correct number of images.

Comment: You are not clear since starting .... come up with what you exactly you want. I 'll post answer accordingly.

Comment: I can't go this way, what if AspectOrder = 4, not 3.The number of image tags has to be equal to the value of deck.aspectOrder

Comment: Check my update. Now you can adjust it with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

*ngFor could help? *ngFor with a made-up array of (deck.aspectOrder) items.
Check out the app.component.ts in [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tfUz06QkNTwhB7oRh4Gp?p=preview).

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="deck.aspectOrder>0">{{deck.aspectOrder}} orders
      <div>
        <div *ngFor="#item of arr; #i=index">order {{i+1}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  deck: {aspectOrder:number}
  arr: []
  ngOnInit() {
    this.deck = {aspectOrder:3};
    this.arr = Array(this.deck.aspectOrder);
  }
}
```